# Jupyter notebook, output more than one expression from cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I want to show the result of an intergation, done in SymPy as an Output in Jupyter with MathJax. Everything works, but I wanted to adjust the output a bit, so that instead of the following:
[image: Current Ouput]

I would get this output:
[image: Desired output]
(Please ignore the arctan() thing.)

I have tried to achieve this by doing something like that:

```
from IPython.display import Math
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
f=(-2*x-1)/(pow(x,2)+2)
Math('F(x)=')
integrate(f,x)
Math('+C')
```

But unfortunately only the last output of the cell is shown, so my question is if it is possible to merge multiple outputs into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `printing.default_latex`, which returns the expression in LaTex as a string:

```
from IPython.display import Math
import sympy
from sympy.interactive import printing

x = sympy.var('x')
f=(-2*x-1)/(pow(x,2)+2)

Math('F(x) = {} + C'.format(printing.default_latex(sympy.integrate(f, x))))
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `sympy.latex`?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try looking at the "Display Math Operation" function I have been fiddling with. You can try it on mybinder:[image: Binder]. It accepts things like `dmo(p = n*R*T/V)` makes the assignment to `p` and outputs a typeset version of the latex string `p=\frac{nRT}{V}`. The eventual goal is to get `dmo(diff(p,T))` to output a typeset version of `\frac{\partial p}{\partial T} = \frac{nR}{V}`. When I have more time, I am going to dig into the rendering in sympy and see if I can get options put into the actual operations, such as `diff` and `int`. The special `Derivative` and `Integrate` operations were also designed for rendering just those operations.

Follow the link in binder to the github repository if you have specific comments or suggestions.